# How can I maintain conversations in MS Outlook using email headers?

Tags: email, header, outlook, smtp

I have the following problem. My java code is sending emails using smtp mail server. This emails have to be grouped in some sort of threads (like conversations in Exchange). And this conversations have to be viewed properly (as conversations :-)) in MS Outlook. Is there some email headers that could be utilized. I've bumped into "In-reply-To" header, but it doesn't seem to do the trick in Outlook. Any suggestions?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: The proper header to use is `References:` but I don't know whether Outlook honors it; Microsoft have a devastating track record when it comes to these things.  See also http://cr.yp.to/immhf/thread.html

Comment: The Discourse guys went through this, it sounds like using both `In-Reply-To:` and `References:` does the trick, though it's not entirely clear and I haven't verified this. https://meta.discourse.org/t/emails-are-not-threaded-in-outlook-2013/16501

Answer (score 0):

Use Thread-Index MIME header. See [Tracking Conversations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765583.aspx) on MSDN for details on how PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX property is constructed.

Comment: says exactly nothing about how you generate this header (if you're not using MS tech stack)

Comment: The format of the PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX property is documented. All you need to do is base64 encode it.